# How can I test my CDN?

Tags: cdn

I have what seems like it must be a super simple and common question, although I can't find a straightforward answer to it online.

Let's say I want to compare the load time of a particular file in the US and in Europe, first with no CDN and then with CDN, to make sure the CDN actually did something.

How can I do this?

Comment: you may also find [jare.io](http://www.jare.io) useful, a free and instant CDN

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to test a web application there are many sites that can help you evaluating your performance, for example besides the usual gomez/keynote:

- [webpagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org)
- [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com)

you can actually do a comparative test running first against the origin and then the accelerated version on your CDN.

However if you just want to test the download speed of a file you could use curl or ab first on the origin and then on the cdn, consider also doing that from other locations taking advantage of services such as amazon aws that allows you to create a free *nix virtual machine in US/Ireland etc.